# About SelectNext procedure in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi-xe2

I'm having the next problem with SELECTNEXT and FINDNEXTCONTROL procedures in Delphi XE2 (Update 4 under WinXP Pro 32b), these procedures aren't working correctly. When a control gets focus and I try to pass to next control with the code below, it does not simply work:

```
procedure TformMain.cbServicioKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key=#13 then
    SelectNext(TWinControl(Sender), True, True);
end;
```

I've reviewed the code for FINDNEXTCONTROL and I've created a similar procedure and I've detected the problem is in these lines:

```
function TWinControl.FindNextControl(CurControl: TWinControl;
  GoForward, CheckTabStop, CheckParent: Boolean): TWinControl;
...........
    GetTabOrderList(List);
    if List.Count > 0 then
    begin
      StartIndex := List.IndexOf(CurControl);
...........
end;
```

For any weird reason, procedure GETTABORDERLIST gives a list with valid references except for the current control focused, it does that LIST.INDEXOF returns -1, and the position in LIST object for current control focused is taken for another object whose NAME property is an empty string.

I developed this code:

```
procedure TformMain.GoNextControl(T: TWinControl; CheckTabStop: Boolean);
var
  vParent, vNextChild : TWinControl;
  List : TList;
  CurIndex, i : Integer;
  S:String;
begin
  vParent:= Self; //T.Parent;
  vNextChild:= nil;

  List:= TList.Create;
  try
    vParent.GetTabOrderList(List);
    if List.Count > 0 then
    begin
      //CurIndex:= List.IndexOf(T);
      CurIndex:= -1;
      for i:= 0 to List.Count-1 do begin
        S:= TWinControl(List[i]).Name;
        if S = EmptyStr then
        begin
          CurIndex:= i;
          Break;
        end;
      end;
  ...........................
```

Anyone has a response for this anomaly or a better solution? Thanks in advance.

d

Comment: File a bug report to QC.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TfrmMain.ControlKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if Key = #13 then
  begin
    SelectNext(ActiveControl, TRUE, TRUE);
    Key := #0;
  end;
end;
```